# Advanced Installer v12.7.2 - need to download installer

Tags: visual-studio

I need to find an older version of Advanced Installer - specifically v12.7.2 - I know this is really old - for reasons out of my control this is the version I have to use.  Could anyone point me where to download this installer?  The website is up to v18 and I can't find anywhere there to get older versions.

Comment: You can download the older versions from the website but you have have a maintenance plan for them: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link of the company website https://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html
[image]

If you have a license key, enter it here:  https://www.advancedinstaller.com/customer-information.html

Otherwise, you can contact the company and they may be able to find it for you.